# Fields over sums of fractions and isomorphism

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Suppose I have,
$$
a = (3 + \sqrt{-7})^{1/2} + \frac{1}{(3 + \sqrt{-7})^{1/2}}
$$

What can I infer about $\mathbb{Q}(a)$? 
And how do I find out if $\mathbb{Q}(a)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[x]/<px^2+qx+r>$ for some given $p,q,r \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%283+%2B+%5Csqrt%7B-7%7D%29%5E%7B1%2F2%7D+%2B+%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%283+%2B+%5Csqrt%7B-7%7D%29%5E%7B1%2F2%7D%7D) tells us that the minimal polynomial of $a$ is $16 x^4 - 166 x^2 + 529$.

Comment: There are infinitely many elements in your field because $\Bbb{Q}$ already has infinitely many elements. Therefore I remove the inappropriate tag [tag:finite-fields].

Comment: The polynomial $f(x)$ lhf gave you has $a$ as a zero, and factors as $(x^2+1)^2$ modulo $3$, so over $\Bbb{Q}$ it is either irreducible or a product of two irreducible quadratics. The polynomial $f(x)$ is even. So if it factors as $f(x)=g(x)h(x)$, then we also have $f(x)=f(-x)=g(-x)h(-x)$. So either you have A) $g(x)=g(-x)$ and $h(x)=h(-x)$, or B) you have $g(-x)=h(x)$. It should not be too difficult to rule out both possibilities (recall that we can assume the factors to have integer coefficients). Good luck!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen You don't like the naive algorithm? Multiplying by $16$ to get an algebraic integer, we know the absolute value of its possible conjugates, so we know an upper bound for the integer coefficients of its minimal polynomial (but not its degree), it remains to enumerate and rule out numerically.

Comment: LOL @reuns. I am getting older, and apparently no longer scan all the alternative approaches to spot the simplest (or pedagogically optimal).